# Laravel Pivot Column Filtering

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, laravel

My codes:

```
$course   = Course::find(1);
$teachers = $course->Users()->where('role_id', 1)->get();
$students = $course->Users()->where('role_id', 2)->get();
```

In this solution, I have two different user types. Users() function is a belongsToMany relationship.

```
public function Users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'course_users')->withPivot('role_id');
}
```

And my course_users table columns: user_id, course_id, role_id

This codes running properly.

But, when I looked to queries, I saw two SQL queries for this situation. I want to use only one query and get only filtered values to suitable variables for performance. How can I do it?

I tried below code. But it only fetches first variable $teachers, but not $students.

```
$users    = $course->Users();
$teachers = $users->where('role_id', 1)->get();
$students = $users->where('role_id', 2)->get();
```

What is your opinions?
Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks. I solved like this.

```
$users = $course->Users()->whereIn('role_id', [1, 2])->get();
$teachers = $users->where('pivot.role_id', 1);
$students = $users->where('pivot.role_id', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

If having just one query is important, you can load the data like this:

```
$users = $course->Users()->whereIn('role_id', [1, 2])->get();
```

And then use the collection to filter data:

```
$teachers = $users->where('role_id', 1);
$students = $users->where('role_id', 2);
```

Comment: i tried that, $users fetching 3 items. but $teachers and $students items are empty. what else can the problem be?